# JQuery POST to Spring MVC Controller and parsing result in success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have integrated jQuery into a Spring MVC application.  I have a form on my JSP page and I am doing an ajax POST to send the form to the controller:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '/MyApp/search/searchResults',
                        data : $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success : function(data) {
                            $("#tabs-4").append(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

The success function will load the data into a new tab.   What I am finding is that `data` returns the HTML of my original page (from which I submitted).  Instead, I would like to be able to parse the ModelAndView object that is being returned from the controller.  For example:

```
${searchResults.searchStr}
```

Is it normal for `data` to return the page HTML?  Is there anyway that I can parse the ModelAndView object in the success function, and then pass it to my new tab div?

Here is my Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchResults(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "search") SearchVO search,
        BindingResult result) {

    // Set the view and search object
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("newSearch");
    mv.addObject("searchResults", searchResults);

    return mv;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your browser, can you use Firebug or Developer Tools to verify that the correct URL is being requested with AJAX and that the correct stuff is being sent through `data`? Also, can you debug in your controller to make sure the request is making it into that particular method? And are you sure your "newSearch" view is pointing to what you expect? You might want to add `cache: false` to your AJAX call

Comment: I added a breakpoint to the controller, and it is definitely receiving the correct data. After using Firebug to debug the ajax call, I can see that data contains the html of the original page. I tried adding cache:false but I cannot see any difference...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can return the html content from the controller to your ajax function. If you are interested in to use the instance in the jsp you would have to serialize it in to json and send it. Using jquery you could render it on the jsp. For example,

```
//Controller
public @ResponseBody<Class_name> search(...){
     return searchResults;
}

//jsp

function renderResult(){
   $.ajax({
    url:'url',
    dataType:'json',
    ...
    ..
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
       $.each(data, function(k, v){
       $('#my_div').append(...k,v...);
}
}
});
}
```

Looking at your requirement I would suggest you to use the first method where you return the html itself and the jsp page which you return could be render with the searchResults.

Comment: I tried this out, but I don't seem to be getting any data back this way. I added a breakpoint to the $.each function, and it is never reached.